# What Statistical Test to choose for data of sales numbers.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am trying to figure this out (i am new to hypothesis testing):

I have gathered 'purchase data' for some products over a period of time. I have two groups: One group is made of the normal-typical buyers, while the other group is shown a specific product advertisement. I need to see if the advertisement has some effect on the second group.

the data looks like this:

$\text{group}_1=\{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0\}$

and

$\text{group}_2=\{1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0\}$

The 0 depicts that a customer bought something else while 1 corresponds to the advertised product.

is t-test an option or something else like Whitney test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural test to use is a test of proportions of two populations. If $p_1$ is the proportion of advertised people who buy the product and $p_2$ is the population proportion of normal buyers, the hypotheses are:

$$H_0: p_1\le p_2\\
H_1: p_1>p_2$$

You can search google to see the details of the procedure.